# probability of choosing 3 as natural number

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

let's say we want to select a natural number, what's the probability of selecting 3 In other words $P(3)=?$
If we suppose it is 0* then the probability of choosing a natural number $P(N)=P(0)+P(1)+...=0+0+...+0=0$ which is wrong since it should be equal to 1.

---

**Why I chose 0 exactly?**

well because in my previous post we proved that the probability of choosing a real number in $[0,1]$ and that it is equal to $1/2$ is $0$.

Comment: The question is not well posed.  There is no uniform distribution on the natural numbers, or on any countable set.

Comment: @lulu so P(3) is undefined?

Comment: One way to get a sensible question would be to define $p_n$ to be the desired probability assuming you take the uniform distribution on $\{1,\cdots, n\}$.  Then let $n$ tend to infinity.  In that case, we easily see that $p_n=\frac 1n$ and of course $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n=0$.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw You speak of "selecting a natural number". That makes it sound as if every natural number should have equal chances to be selected. This however is not possible. If P(3)=p and p=0 then we run into the trouble exposed in your question and if we go for p positive then we get $P(\mathbb N)=+\infty$. So in both cases no probability measure. In that sense you could say that "P(3) is not defined".

Comment: You could define the probability of choosing a natural number using some convergent series. For example $P(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=1$.

Comment: @drhab I am not the one who posted the question.  :)

Comment: @drhab I would like to add that the equation stated in the question only works for finite sets.

Comment: @Darsen what do u mean by "define the probability"? it is not allowed at all. you can't define the probability of getting 2 when rolling a dice to be 1/100? it is 1/6

Comment: @john Sure you can. However what you create by that is a "bad model" of the situation that you describe. If in exercizes you are asked about rolling dice then you are expected to come up with a "good model". I tried to explain that a good model does not exist if it is demanded that all numbers of $\mathbb N$ have equal probability to be selected. Darsen told you that this does not exclude the existence of different sort of models.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Sorry for wrong adressing.

Comment: Dont think of zero as zero in this case.  Think of $P(3)=0$ as being some infinitesimally small but non-zero value.  The total sum over all naturals is going to be a probability of 1.  But the probably of choosing any one of the infinite naturals is inconceivably unlikely.  Think of it like playing darts on a round dart board.  Youre guaranteed to hit somewhere on the board, but the probability of hitting any singular predetermined point in this space is the same kind of 0.  Put it this way.... a probability of 0 does NOT mean *impossible*.